# How to display just for example 100 words of an post?

Tags: python, django, view, blogs

I have made something like this. If the reader clicks on "Weiterlesen" then it should display the whole text. But first i want to display an range of words (for example 100)
Can i set range[:100] into {{ post.text|linebreaksbr }} ??

Thanks for your answers

```
{% block content %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="post">
                <div class="date">
                    {{ post.published_date }}
                </div>
                <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-default">Weiterlesen</a>

            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Check out the [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in [`truncatewords`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) filter does exactly what you want.

```
<p>{{ post.text|truncatewords:200|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```